# Android customization Galaxy Note

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, custom-roms, backup, samsung-galaxy-note

Recently, Android ICS has been released in my country (Hungary) also for the Samsung Galaxy Note. That's cool, the phone updated itself to Android 4.0.3 and at first sight it was really cool and fast. But...
To be honest, the Wi-Fi disconnects and the battery gets empty in half of a day... These 2 make me really angry and I was thinking about rooting, which I have successfully done today, but it still didn't help at all on my problems. Okay, the UI might be a little faster...

So. I thought I might have to change the ROM to a custom one.

Now I have more questions about this:

- I wish to modify my phone on a way I can easily turn it back to the factory state (no wonder, warranty). How to do this/is it possible?
- Is it possible to "put up" more ROMs and when I'm turning on the phone just select the one I want to use (just like you'd install more OSs on a desktop computer)?
- I would also want to know what are my options for a custom ROM for a Galaxy Note WITHOUT losing my S-Pen functionality, so which ROMs should I count in?
- How to freakin' achieve these above questions if everything is ok? =D

Thanks in advance! =)

(Links and experiences are welcome also...)

Comment: Üdv itt! I think your question would be better off as three separate ones. I could answer parts of it but not the whole so I would get downvoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only devices with NVIDIA Tegra chips in them can be completely restored to factory conditions.

When you root your phone, the warranty is void, and there is no sending it back.

You can Back-Up a ROM and before booting, wipe the phone's ROM and restore one of the backed up ROMs. 
Backing up and restoring is very time consuming, though. 
You would only want to do that so you could perhaps have an AOSP ROM, a TouchWhiz ROM, and perhaps a CM9 or AOKP ROM as well-- 
Trust me, you'll be too busy flashing new updates to worry about switching between backups.

Head over to http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=1346 for the low down on the rest. You can never read enough, really--

The different ROMs will be under the Development section.

Comment: Actually, I am backing up the phone now. I see now what you mean under time consuming... =D Anyway, Samsung can go to hell, I can't believe they have screwed up Android ICS so much... So if warranty goes for a freakin' awesome smartphone, so be it...

Comment: Uh... Your very first sentence is blatantly wrong. Zte blade and Huawei U8220 are two that can be. There must be many others.

Comment: Oh! Well, I've never handled a Huawei-- But no- there are not many that I've come across.

HTC, Samsung-- cannot be reverted. 

LG, some Motorola's-- can be restored to factory condition-- but they all have NVIDIAs in them- 

And what do you mean, benqus? 
I don't own a Samsung, myself, but they're top of the line! I would rather have a GSII than the HTC XE
Is TouchWhiz that bad? -- I mean, it's gotta be better than what HTC did with Sense-- 

-- I highly recommend Apex Launcher ontop of either CM9 or AOKP for the best  ICS experience--